# ANTLR how to get expression token

Tags: c#, antlr

I'm writing a really basic compiler/parser as a learning project.

```
grammar C;

file: expr;

expr: '(' expr ')'                     # parens
    | '-'<assoc=right> expr            # Negate
    | expr op=('*'|'/') expr           # MulDiv
    | expr op=('+'|'-') expr           # AddSub
    | INT                              # int
    ;

INT: '0' | [1-9][0-9]*;

WS: [ \t\n\r] -> skip;
```

Here is an example of the events on the negate operation

```
public override void ExitNegate([NotNull] CParser.NegateContext context)
{
    var children = context.children;
    if (children[1].ChildCount == 1)
    {
        assembler.Mov32RI(allocator.AllocateRegister().ToString().ToLower(), -int.Parse(children[1].GetText()));
    }
    else
    {
        assembler.NegateR(allocator.Top().ToString());
    }
    base.ExitNegate(context);
}
```

I'm using

```
 children[1].ChildCount == 1
```

to basically mean 'if child is an int' since that is the only grammar rule I have that could mean that in this context (I think). Is there a way to get the expression token in this situation so I'm actually looking for INT? In a more complex grammar I would want my logic to much more explicit.

Edit: I'm not looking for improvements in the grammaer but how can I use the context argument in the listener to determine if the expression part is an integer (ideally i'd think check for an INT token).

Answer (score 0):

In `ExitNegate` you can obviously only get an `expr` node, as that is what your grammar specifies. You could drill down in that context until you find a leave node, which is then your `INT` token.

However, it makes probably more sense to listen to `Exitint` instead where you then know for sure this is the `INT` you are looking for. If in doubt you can examine the parent of the given context to see if that is the `expr` context.